# How to load sample.xlsx in oracle data base using sql loader

Tags: sql-loader

I am trying to load my data which is in excel format but i am not able to do that.could you please help me on this.

Comment: Please edit your question and be more specific about the problem. What errors are you getting? What efforts have you made on your side to fix the problem? Have you tried searching on the net and seeing if a similar issue exists?

Answer (score 0):

It would have been easier for us if you came up with some screenshots or codes but If you want to load it using SQL Loader, you'll need to save it as a CSV first. Then the delimiter will be a commas, which you have.

---

Or you can load it as Excel using SQL Developer:

http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/04/how-to-import-from-excel-to-oracle-with-sql-developer/

---

Hope this helps!!